# Knockout Foreach Javascript function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach

Is it possible to declare a javascript function in your knockout foreach binding?  I want to generate a list from a javascript function outside of my view model.

```
 <select class="form-control" data-bind="foreach: { data: function() { // return list values } }">
 <option data-bind="text: Value, attr: { value: Value }"></option>
            </select>
```

Comment: why do u want to do this? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to pull from a globally defined javascript list.

Comment: You should call that global list from your VM, its there for that reason

Answer (score 1):

No quite sure what you are trying to achieve with `<option data-bind="text: Value, attr: { value: Value }"></option>`.

Have a look  at my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/72GWJ/) for a few different setups. It contains usages of both `options` and `foreach` bindings on a `select` element.

To answer the question, you provide a function in your `viewModel` to provide the desired data. As long as your viewModel can "access" the data, the function will provide it to the binding. If the data were to be a simple list of literals, then all that is required :

Javascript:

```
var listOfLiterals = function() { return  ["One", "Two", "Three"] };

  var viewModel = {
     selectedLiteral: ko.observable(),  
     getLiterals: function() {
       return listOfLiterals();
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: getLiterals(), value: selectedLiteral"></select>
```